# WL 6.1.0.02 - How to pass a JSON Object from native iOS and native Android to HTTP Javascript Adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

Our project is supposed to re-use existing Adapters that expect JSON objects as input parameters into the Adapter procedures.

When we try to call the Adapter using:

```
WLProcedureInvocationData *myInvocationData = [[WLProcedureInvocationData alloc] initWithAdapterName:@"UserProfileAdapter" procedureName:@"getUserProfile"];

myInvocationData.parameters = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"{\"userEmail\" : \"xxx@xxx.com\"}", nil];
```

then the input object that is passed to the Adapter procedure is not a Javascript object, but a javascript string.

In order to make a object out of it, we would always need to parse the input from a string to an object using:

```
input = JSON.parse(input);
```

since we are reusing existing code that is in production with a hybrid app, this is not an option, since with the hyrbid app this works fine.

How can we pass JSON to a Javascript adapter so that the Adapter automatically creates an input object and not a string?

Answer (score 1):

The answer we found was for Swift and for Android ... did not try ObjC anymore.

iOS:

```
//Create JSON Object with keys and values
let jsonObject: [String: AnyObject] = [
                "userName": "xxx@xxx.com",
                "password": "12345"
            ]

let procedureData = WLProcedureInvocationData(adapterName: "AuthAdapter", procedureName: "login")
procedureData.parameters = [jsonObject]
```

Android:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("\"userName\":\"xxx@xx.com\",\"password\":\"1234\"}");
Object[] params = new Object[]{jsonObj};

WLProcedureInvocationData invocationData = new WLProcedureInvocationData("AuthAdapter", "login");
invocationData.setParameters(params);
```

We have not tried anything with deeper nested JSON structures yet and this might still be troublesome, but for a basic JSON this works fine for us now.